# Method based serialization with Spring Data ElasticSearch 4.x (without Jackson)

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, jackson, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are running a Java, Spring application which indexes to ElasticSearch, using Spring Data Elasticsearch. Recently my team has moved from version 3.x to 4.x. This upgrade removes the Jackson mapper according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping This document contains the following quote:

> Using the MappingElasticsearchConverter now covers all these cases.

Yet, I have not found a way to resolve the following. We used to build up certain fields in ElasticSearch by having a method in our models that contain logical functions on the fields of this model. For example:

```
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  String getFullName(){
    return firstName  + " " + lastName;
  }
}
```

Using version 3.x the getFullName() method would be serialized as default by Jackson, filling our ElasticSearch index with a 'fullName' field. In version 4.x this information is left out from our index. The annotations in 4.x seem to be only supporting serialization options for fields, not methods. Jackson annotations (@JsonInclude for example) obviously do not work here anymore.

How would I be able to map method results to a field in ElasticSearch with Spring Data ElasticSearch 4.x ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding the `@AccessType` annotation with the `PROPERTY` parameter to the method:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.AccessType;

@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
String getFullName(){
  return firstName  + " " + lastName;
}
```

Please note, that Spring Data Elasticsearch needs a setter as well, so you will need to define an empty method:

```
void setFullName(String ignore){}
```

If you are good with the default mappings that Elasticsearch will provide for this text property, that's it.

I think it should be possible to use this without a setter and besides that, it should be possible to put the `@Field` annotation on the method to be able to have a proper mappings for such properties.

I [created a Jira issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-916) for this.

**Edit 1.10.2022:**

This is implementewd now and will be available in the next version (5.0.RC)

Comment: despite my first answer, there is a way to have it work, I updated my answer accordingly